# How Pass variable from Controllers to Model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I want to pass $id from my Controllers to Model, please help me

this my Controllers

```
class OrderController extends Controller
{
 public function show($id,Request $request) {
$data= order_list::select('*')
            ->where('t_order_list.id_order', $id)
            ->get();
}
}
```

how to pass $id to my model

```
class order_list extends Model
{
    protected $table = "t_order_list";

    protected $fillable = ['id_order','id_product','id_variant','qty_order'];

    protected $with = ['variant_list'];

    public function variant_list($id){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Model\variant','id','id_variant')
                ->join('t_color','t_variant.id_pcolor','=','t_color.id')
                ->join('t_size','t_variant.id_psize','=','t_size.id')
                ->join('t_subcategory','t_variant.id_pcategory_sub','=','t_subcategory.id')
                ->join('t_order_list as d', 't_variant.id', '=', 'd.id_variant')
                ->select(['t_variant.*','t_color.code_pcolor','t_size.code_psize','t_color.hex_pcolor'
                    ,'t_color.hex_pcolor_2','t_color.hex_pcolor_3',
                    't_subcategory.name_pcategory_sub','d.qty_order'])
                    ->where('d.id_order', $id);                  
    }
```

[this my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STNEQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Call from Controller like OrderList::variant_list($id) and define function like

```
public static function variant_list($id){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Model\variant','id','id_variant')
            ->join('t_color','t_variant.id_color','=','t_color.id')
            ->join('t_size','t_variant.id_size','=','t_size.id')
            ->join('t_subcategory','t_variant.id_subcategory','=','t_subcategory.id')
            ->join('t_order_list as d', 't_variant.id', '=', 'd.id_variant')
            ->select(['t_variant.*','t_color.code_color','t_size.code_size','t_color.hex_color'
                ,'t_color.hex_color_2','t_color.hex_color_3',
                't_subcategory.name_subcategory','d.qty_order']);

}
```

Comment: Share Error details

Comment: are you passing $id to OrderList::variant_list($id)  ?

Comment: i dunno how to passing $id to model, i try Orderlist::variant($id) but still error,

Answer (score 0):

**You can pass simply the variable from controller to models.**

**For Normal method:-**

**Controller:-UserController**

```
public function test(){
    $id = "A";
    $user = new User; //create object
    $user->passValue($id);
}
```

**Model:- User**

```
public function passValue($id){
  echo $id;
}
```

**For Static method:-**

```
public function test(){
    $id = "A";
    User::passValue($id);
}
```

**Model:- User**

```
public static function passValue($id){
  echo $id;
}
```

Comment: your answer its right but not solved my problem, because first i'll call $data for check all product, in product had many variant in different table, well i need one to many relation, if u have any idea pls tell me